# Auto 301 to full post permalink? (using /posts/%post_id%/%postname%)

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess, redirect

I update my permalink structure to /post/%post_id%/%postname%, but if someone uses a URL like /post/1234 instead of the full URL of /post/1234/bingo-rulz, WordPress shows the post without giving a 301 to the full URL.  Isn't this poor SEO?  Sites like tumblr and stackexchange auto 301 to the full URL.  Any hacks/code/plugins/settings/etc to fix this?  thanks

p.s. /post/1234/blah does get a 301 to /post/1234/bingo-rulz but /post/1234 does not and ends up in two separate URLs to the same content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have permalink include ID and Name, but only use ID (like tumblr)?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/have-permalink-include-id-and-name-but-only-use-id-like-tumblr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I found a solution...  Since anything after the %post_id%/*_*_ will redirect to the full slug, a simple RewriteRule in the .htaccess file appears to do the trick.  I had to place it above other RewriteRules and this is working for me.

RewriteRule ^post/(\d*)/?\z$ http://noahcoad.com/post/$1/a [R=301,L]